# i cant get socket.io address

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

This is the html of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
    
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var server = http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server is listening on port', server.address().port)
})
```

It gives this error on node

```
node:events:505
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
    
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1380:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1516:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CodeNinja Guest\Desktop\Practice Node\practice\5.01\server.js:21:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1407:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
        code: 'EADDRINUSE',
        errno: -4091,
        syscall: 'listen',
        address: '::',
        port: 3000
    }
```

And on web inspect this error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't know know if I understood this right, But I think it isn't getting the socket file.

Comment: The error states that the port is already in use. Did you try changing it to a different value like 3001? If you really need port 3000, you need to terminate the process using it.

Comment: I closed all my terminals and restarted the vscode and it worked.
is there any logic to this? because this kind of error happened before as well and it fixed after restarting vscode some how

Comment: nvm I got the problem.
I had opened multiple terminals and 1 terminal was running with port 3000
that's why when I closed all my terminals it started working

Comment: Was about to say that you might have more than on terminal open and listening on that port. This is a common mistake i also made. :)